# Continuously call method in backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I really need consulting in a problem about `BackgroundWorker`. My application, while doing other tasks, shall periodically check the connection between my PC and others(by means of ping). There are 19 remote computers to check, which takes about 3 min to ping. So for sure I put this ping method in a `BackgroundWorker`. And I'm using this code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        LoadList();   // This's the method to ping            
        sw.Stop();
        // Console.WriteLine("Elapesd time:"+ sw.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString());

        int elapsed = 1000 - (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        if (elapsed <= 0)
            elapsed = 0;
        Thread.Sleep(elapsed);
        //}
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

I want that every 1s the `Loadlist()` runs to check if a remote pc is reachable or no. But the odd thing is, if a remote pc is disconnected, after 1s I can find that out (in my list this pc changes color), but if it is newly connected, after maybe 3 minutes I could find that out! I can't understand why is that! Somebody could explain me about this? or anybody has a better solution for me to achieve my goal? Thank you in advance!

Edit: This is my Loadlist() method:

```
 private void LoadList()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
        {
            address[i] = "10.4." + i.ToString() + ".2";
            deposit[i] = PingHost(address[i]); //My PingHost() method returns a bool

            if (deposit[i])   // if this deposit[i] is true, the address[i] is pingable
                treeView2.Nodes[i].BackColor = Color.Green;

            else
            {
                address[i] = "10.2." + i.ToString() + ".2";
                deposit[i] = PingHost(address[i]);
                if (deposit[i])
                    treeView2.Nodes[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
                else
                    treeView2.Nodes[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code of `LoadList`

Comment: Now I'm confused.. what exactly is your question? Are you asking how to periodically call a method, as the title suggests? Or are you asking why it's taking you 3 minutes to find out whether a remote pc is reachable?

Comment: If you're asking about both, consider restricting this question to one topic, and asking about the other in a different question.

Comment: @dcastro Yes I'm asking about both. Of course there's someone who could recommand me a new method like you, or someone who could explain me why and then recommand me a new method. By the way for your suggestion, I shall make a timer1_tick event and put my Loadlist() inside right? When the Loadlist() implements, isn't there a conflict with what my application currently is doing?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), not a background worker. The timer won't take any of the process's resources inbetween ticks, whereas a sleeping background worker will.

If this is a long-living timer, make sure you keep a strong reference to the timer so that it won't be garbage collected.